# get name of author who commented using a non-facebook login provider

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

In my facebook comments plugin, I have the login providers enabled. Now I have a comment like the following:

[image: comment]

I tried to [access this comment from the Graph API](http://graph.facebook.com/10150285351444419_24110727) but it seems that the `from` field in there is null.
Next I tried to play around and see what the FQL table shows [so I went to this URL](http://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=select%20fromid%20from%20comment%20where%20id=%2710150285351444419_24110727%27) and I saw from there a `fromid` field. So assuming this was a userid of some sort, I put it in graph API, but I don't think it exists in there. Now I'm wondering how to get the string **Scott Faber** off of Graph API, does anybody know? Thanks in advance.